# Remove Each letter by pressing back button in Android. (code works)

Tags: java, android, xml

by clicking on the cancel button, each letter in the edit text is removed.

```
  // click listener 
     btncancel.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                String remove = txt.getText().toString();
                if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(remove)){
                    remove  = remove.substring(0, remove.length() - 1); //clearing one by one 
                    txt.setText(remove); }
                    txt.clearFocus();
     });
```

Comment: and what is the question?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the question is but as the title suggests, if you want to do it using back button, you can override method called onBackPressed(), remove the super call and run your code.

Comment: code is working fine.thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

this is very simple solution to do that

```
 // click listener 
     btncancel.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                
        txt.setText(removeLastChar(txt.getText().toString())); 

       }
        });
public String removeLastChar(String s) {
    if (s.length() > 0) {
        return s[0..-1]
    }
    return s
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**100% it's will work for you..**

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        removeLastChar(binding.tvName);
    }

    public void removeLastChar(TextView s) {
        if (s.length() > 0) {
            String remove = s.getText().toString();
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(remove)){
                remove  = remove.substring(0, remove.length() - 1);
                s.setText(remove); }
            s.clearFocus();
        }else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```